# macro that defines a comment

Tags: spacing, comments

The Wikibooks book on LaTeX [mentions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting#Multi-line_comments) the following way of defining a macro for (possibly multi-line) comments:

```
\newcommand{\comment}[2]{#2}
```

with the argument that

```
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}
```

can produce unwanted space.

But is this really the best way? Does this macro work in all contexts, even at the very end of a file? **What is the best way of defining a comment macro that works in the largest number of circumstances?** (Of course there is no way to define a comment macro that works *everywhere*.)

Comment: I'm even more convinced that the Wikibooks on LaTeX are *not* to be recommended.

Comment: @egreg Yeah, there is lots of room for improvement there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any definition as a command isn't really a comment, You can not comment out `%` or `{`  for example, and it is not invisible to other commands.

```
\fbox
 %  \ { \hhhh
 {aaa}
```

Boxes `aaa` as the *real* comment with `%` hides all the junk in the line, but any `\comment` macro will not work in that position, even

```
\fbox
 \comment{xxx}
 {aaa}
```

The argument to `\fbox` is just `\comment` and `{xxx}` and `{aaa}` are still in the input stream and things go badly wrong.

```
! Argument of \comment has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.24      \comment
                  {xxx}
```

If you add `\ignorespaces` to avoid spacing issues then it doesn't expand to nothing so that

```
\newcommand\comment[1]{\ignorespaces}

\typeout{aaaa\comment{bbb}ccc}
```

produces

```
aaaa\ignorespaces ccc
```

whereas

```
\newcommand\comment[1]{}

\typeout{aaaa\comment{bbb}ccc}
```

produces

```
aaaaccc
```

Using a trailing `#2` to remove space is dangerous unless you know you are in a very restricted context where there will be no `{}` groups.

```
\newcommand\comment[2]{#2}
\comment{aaa} {\bfseries bbb} ccc
```

The `ccc` will be in bold as the `\comment` macro will have taken the entire `{\bfseries bbb}` as `#2` but only returned `\bfseries bbb` without the brace group to the input stream, so the `\bfseries` is no longer scoped to just `bbb`.

Comment: Do `aaaa\ignorespaces ccc` and `aaaaccc` produce the same output, or, if not, what is the difference between them?

Comment: In a message to the user printed on the terminal and in the log the difference between `aaaaccc` and `aaaa\ignorespaces ccc` is that the second one has the unwanted characters `\ignorespaces ` in the middle of the message. If you are not in a message it depends what `aaaa` really is for example if it is a test with `\@ifnextchar` (eg looking for an optional argument) then it will see `c` (or perhaps `[` in a real example) in one case but will see `\comment` in the other.

Comment: Answer taken for the details, though the credit is shared with user @Werner.

Answer (score 12):

For me it makes more sense to use

```
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{\ignorespaces}
```

since it takes a single argument, gobbles it and ignores any spaces afterwards. Here are some examples of its usage relative to other `\comment`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\commentA}[1]{}
\newcommand{\commentB}[2]{#2}
\newcommand{\commentC}[1]{\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
\commentA{This is a long comment and can extend over multiple lines, etc.} But it won't show. \par
\commentB{This is a long comment and can extend over multiple lines, etc.} But it won't show. \par
\commentC{This is a long comment and can extend over multiple lines, etc.} But it won't show. \par
Something before. \commentA{This is a long comment and can extend over multiple lines, etc.} But it won't show. \par
Something before. \commentB{This is a long comment and can extend over multiple lines, etc.} But it won't show. \par
Something before. \commentC{This is a long comment and can extend over multiple lines, etc.} But it won't show. \par
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for its straightforwardness; this is what I'll be using.