# How are space tokens and empty lines processed by long commands (as their potential arguments)?

Tags: spacing, macros, line-breaking, tex-core, token-lists

How are spaces and empty lines processed by long commands (i.e., those that do not accept paragraph breaks inside)? Are there different space tokens aside from " " and an empty line? It appears that an empty line counts as exactly one empty argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\oneArg}[1]{}
\newcommand{\twoArgs}[2]{}
\newcommand{\threeArgs}[3]{}

\begin{document}

\indent
A \oneArg

B

% output:
% A B


A \twoArgs

B

C

% output:
% A
% C

A \threeArgs

B

C

% output:
% A C

\end{document}
```

And is there anything special one needs to know about math mode in this regard?

One pointer: Some relevant information is in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97650/14996), especially [this discussion thread about `\somecommand *` being legal LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97650/do-starred-commands-eat-up-space-after-them#comment210477_97659).

---

**Addendum:** An interesting detail about short macros (those defined for example with `\newcommand*`): If I add `\newcommand*{\noPar}[1]{#1}` to my source code and try to compile an additional codechunk

```
\noPar{
A \threeArgs

B

C
}
```

the compiler will throw an error. As this is *semantically* not a paragraph break, the long-short distinction between commands should probably be described in terms of empty lines, not paragraph breaks. Or not?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant: an end of a line and a following empty line are equivalent to `\par` which is read in as an argument to your commands. Spaces alone are ignored when scanning for arguments except when they're used as delimiters for the arguments. (... or between delimiters of a delimited argument, or in braces `{ }` ...)

Comment: @cgnieder 1. Make it an answer? 2. Spaces are ignored or are not ignored "between delimiters of a delimited argument"? You mean "spaces are ignored between `}` and `{` of successive arguments' delimiters", correct? And the "in braces" addendum is a bit confusing (surely not all spaces occurring somewhere inside `{ }` are ignored, perhaps only those at the beginning or end, but I though *those* are *not* ignored.

Comment: I don't see the link to math mode: I removed the tag

Comment: A _delimited_ argument cannot be defined through `\newcommand` but it can with `\def`: in `\def\test a#1b{(#1)}` the argument has the delimiters `a` and `b`. In `\test a b` the space between `a` and `b` will not be ignored, similar to `\newcommand\test[1]{(#1)}\test{ }`.

Comment: @cgnieder Are two successive linebreak characters *exactly* equivalent to feeding the command one `\par`? And, what about a non-empty line, i.e. two linebreak characters separated only by space characters?

Comment: _One_ end-of-line is the _same_ as a single space. One end-of-line- followed by an _empty_ line is eqivalent to `\par`, see [Joseph's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98884/5049) and the comments below

Comment: @LoverofStructure About the last addendum: you macro `\noPar` is not long, so it doesn't allow `\par` tokens in its argument; it's obvious that the code raises an error. It has already said many times: a blank line is converted into `\par`, so there's no distinction to be made.

Comment: @egreg Actually, the point of the addendum was to show that it's illegal even though `\threeArgs` is long. This is interesting and imo worth pointing out, as it teaches (a non-expert) something about the order in which things are processed. Not knowing about TeX-internals, it's entirely plausible to assume that `\threeArgs` processes its arguments first. It's about greedy vs lazy evaluation order, though TeX's very special parsing algorithm doesn't quite fit into those categories and makes it tricky to figure out and understand such details.

Comment: @LoverofStructure I disagree: TeX sees `\noPar` and so it absorbs its argument, which happens to contain `\par`. Error.

Comment: @egreg Yes, so this means that `\noPar` does this error checking *before* `\threeArgs` has a chance to eat `\par`, `B`, and `\par`. Why would this be obvious to a non-expert?

Comment: @LoverofStructure Because macro expansion proceeds in the order the tokens are found.

Comment: @egreg But checking that there is no `\par`, which is part of macro *execution* of `\noPar`, happens before `\threeArgs` is executed. I don't see how this order is obvious to a casual user of LaTeX.

Comment: @LoverofStructure There *is* `\par` in the argument of `\noPar`. It doesn't matter what possible macros in the same argument will do with it. I've never encountered such a problem from users.

Comment: @egreg Say you want to apply a comment macro inside of `\noPar`, like what is described [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94666/14996), the comment can be multiple paragraphs. The question is not whether this is a likely thing to occur; my point is that it's something about execution order and parsing that is not obvious (to a non-expert) and needs to be documented, such as *here*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is *technically* "they are not processed" but I don't think that's the answer you want.

If you modify your definitions to

```
\newcommand{\oneArg}[1]{\long\def\a{[#1]}\typeout{\meaning\a}}
\newcommand{\twoArgs}[2]{\long\def\a{[#1][#2]}\typeout{\meaning\a}}
\newcommand{\threeArgs}[3]{\long\def\a{[#1][#2][#3]}\typeout{\meaning\a}}
```

you will see

```
\long macro:->[\par ]
\long macro:->[\par ][B]
\long macro:->[\par ][B][\par ]
```

Assuming normal catcodes are in force a blank line is turned by TeX into the token `\par` (literally the command name token `\par` not the primitive paragraph end function) It does this at a very early stage as characters are being tokenised, so before any token lists are passed to a macro.  So a macro never sees a blank line in its argument. The behaviour is always as if you replace the blank line by `\par` in the input file.

Space tokens are similarly processed at this early stage. Spaces at the end of the line and the beginning of the next are discarded and never tokenised at all so macros have no record of them. (You can not prevent the discarding of space at the end of the line even if you change the catcode of space) and runs of spaces characters only produce one space token. It is the tokens not the file characters that are passed to a macro.

If you have non-delimited arguments as in your example any spaces tokens are skipped while looking for the argument, if you want a space to *be* the argument you need `{ }`. `\par` can be an undelimited argument if the macro is `\long` or an error otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

TeX's tokenization process is important here. When (La)TeX reads *one* newline

```
some text
some more text
```

it converts the newline to a space (with any spaces at the start of the second line ignored): `some text some more text`. However, when TeX reads *two* consecutive newlines it converts to a `\par` token

```
some text

some more text
```

ends up as `some text \par some more text`. (I'm assuming standard setting for `\endlinechar` here.)

Grabbing arguments happens after this process has occurred, so you are not seeing 'blank lines' being read as arguments but rather `\par` tokens. It's `\par` *tokens* in the argument of a command that make the difference between 'short' and 'long' commands, and these have to appear *directly* in the argument to raise an error with a 'short' command.

Comment: So there's a difference between "token `\par`" and "macro name token `\par`" ?

Comment: @tohecz None: what there is a difference between is a token called `\par` (a macro, `\let` to a something, ...) and the `\par` primitive used by TeX internally. See for example `\endgraf`, which is `\let` to the `\par` _primitive_ but is allowed in 'short' arguments as it is not a `\par` token.

Comment: So I still don't understand, at which stage TeX recognizes the difference between `\section{x\par y}` and `\section{x<EOL><EOL>y}` so that the 1st goes through, but the 2nd throws an error?

Comment: @tohecz You never get `\section{x<EOL><EOL>y}`: TeX tokenizes as it reads the argument, so you can only get `\section{x\par y}` (unless you do verbatim-like reading by fiddling with `\endlinechar`).

Comment: What about `<EOL>    <EOL>` with tons of space in between (and possible space before and after)?

Comment: @LoverofStructure TeX is in 'skipping spaces' mode after the first newline, so any intervening spaces are ignored. _The TeXbook_ is the place to read up on this.

Answer (score 3):

(1) White space not containing two `<end-of-line>`s is skipped when scanning for arguments. (2) White-space containing *at least* two `<end-of-lines>` is converted to `\par` and can be passed as an argument.

On the other hand, when TeX scans a definition of a command without `\long`, and spots `\par` (either as `\par` or as (2) above), it throws an error. This is so that you can easier debug wrong grouping. (Remember: `\newcommand` => yes-`\long` and `\newcommand*` => no-`\long`.)

---

As well `\par` in case (2) is a valid not only as an argument, but as an argument delimiter, too. However, the argument will still contain a terminating space token:

```
\def\xy#1\par{x#1y}

Hello \xy World

How are you

\bye
```

Output (one line, remember we "ate" the `\par` using it as a argument delimiter):

> Hello xWorld yHow are you

---

AFAIK this is used in ConTeXt sometimes and it allows you to get rid of many braces, e.g. consider the defintion `\def\Section#1\par{\section{#1}}`, the your code would be:

```
\Section Your well-being

How are you?
```

Output:

> **Your well-being**
>
> How are you?

Comment: I think you need to be clearer on the distinction between space characters in the input file and space _tokens_ as the timing of tokenisation is the entire issue here (compare to my and @Joseph's answers) The skipping of white space tokens when looking for delimited arguments works on token lists and is completely separate from the skipping of space at start and end of line which works on characters only.

Comment: +1 for a good quick answer (This time it was very hard for me to decide which answer to accept: they differ essentially only in the level of "detail vs high-level".)